# SwiftUI: Menu Sort Rule with forward/reverse indication

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to achieve something like in the attached screenshot. I am talking about the circled chevron displaying the forward/reverse order on the selected sorting rule.

[image: screenshot]

When selecting the same sort type, I want to actually use the same selected type but to reverse the order from forward to reverse or other way around.

This the menu I have right now but the button action does not execute at all.
How can I achieve this?

```
Menu {
    Picker("Filtering", selection: viewModel.filterBinding) {
        ForEach(FilterType.allCases) { filterType in
            Text(filterType.rawValue)
                .tag(filterType)
        }
    }
    
    Divider()
    
    Picker("Sorting", selection: viewModel.sortingBinding) {
        ForEach(SortType.allCases) { sortType in
            Button {
                if viewModel.sortType == sortType {
                    viewModel.toggleSortOrder()
                }
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text(sortType.rawValue)
                    Image(systemName: viewModel.sortOrder == .forward ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down")
                        .opacity(viewModel.sortType == sortType ? 1 : 0)
                }
            }
            .tag(sortType)
        }
    }
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle.fill")
}
```

Here are the enums you also need (probably):

```
enum FilterType: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id: Self { self }

    case all = "Al"
    case active = "Active"
    case retired = "Retired"
}

enum SortType: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id: Self { self }

    case brand = "by Brand"
    case model = "by Model"
    case distance = "by Distance"
    case aquisitionDate = " by Aquisition Date"
}
```

Comment: The reason it does not change is beacause there is no change in the value of sortingBinding when tapping on the same item. You need to provoke some kind of change in order to trigger the arrow to toggle up and down. The Picker also has the downside of capturing any touch event it seems. Maybe you need to use some other compnent for that.

Answer (score 0):

I made an implementation to give you a hint on how you could achieve what you want without the Picker item. The issue with the Picker item, as far as my knowledge and testing go, is that it captures the tap events, and does not tell you when you tap on the same item.
Here's what I did:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var show = false
    @State var filterBinding: FilterType = .all
    @State var sortingBinding: SortType = .brand
    @State var ascending = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            
            Button(action: {
                show.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle.fill")
            })
            .overlay {
                if show {
                    SortingList()
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func SortingList() -> some View {
        VStack {
            
            List {
                ForEach(SortType.allCases) { sortType in
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            .opacity(sortingBinding == sortType ? 1 : 0)
                        Text(sortType.rawValue)
                        Image(systemName: self.ascending ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down")
                            .opacity(self.sortingBinding == sortType ? 1 : 0)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if sortType == sortingBinding {
                            self.ascending.toggle()
                            return // <-- Remove this if you want to make the overlay disappear when changing the order type
                        }
                        sortingBinding = sortType
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                            show = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            List {
                ForEach(FilterType.allCases) { filterType in
                    Text(filterType.rawValue)
                        .tag(filterType)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
        .frame(width: 250, height: 500)
    }   
}
```

Now, it is not the best looking, of course, I did not put so much effort into that, I just wanted it to have the intended behavior. You can improve it visually as you like. [image: Reverting sorting order]

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need a picker here at all. Just use the `ForEach` loop inside the menu. And use `Buttons` instead of `Text`.

e.g.:

```
Menu{
    // add all filters to the menu
    ForEach(FilterType.allCases) { filterType in
        if filterType == viewmodel.filterBinding{
            // filter is selected so no action needed the item will be greyed out
            Label(filterType.rawValue, systemImage: "checkmark")
        } else {
            // to change the selection add a button that sets the value in the viewmodel
            Button{
                viewmodel.filterBinding = filterType
            } label: {
                Text(filterType.rawValue)
            }
        }
    }
    Divider()
    // add all sorttypes to the menu
    ForEach(SortType.allCases) { sortType in
        // if the sorting is selected
        if viewmodel.sortingBinding == sortType{
            Button{
                // a second tap on the sorttype will change the sort order
                viewmodel.toggleSortOrder()
            } label: {
                // use a label with the chevron up or down
                Label(sortType.rawValue, systemImage: viewmodel.sortOrder == .forward ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down")
            }
        } else{
            // if a value is selected assign it to the viewmodel
            Button{
                viewmodel.sortingBinding = sortType
            } label: {
                Text(sortType.rawValue)
            }
        }
    }
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle.fill")
}
```

Comment: For this to work, it requires "Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Label<Text, Image>' conform to 'TableRowContent'". Are you facing the same error?

Comment: @RobertBasamac This means there is an error some where in your code. Please edit your question and *add* a [mre] that shows the problem. I´ve tried my solution and it worked just fine.

Comment: I am writing it manually right now and yeah, the error does not occur anymore. :)

Comment: While implementing your solution, I found out that the leading checkmark is missing. If I try to add it, it will replace the chevron image, as inside the menu there can only be one Text and/or one Image. I want to display both of them. To show the selected sort rule (checkmark in leading position) and also the up/down chevron displayed only near the selected sort rule, indicating the sort order.

Comment: @RobertBasamac I don´t think there is much you can do about that as long you want to implement this with the standard elements SwiftUI provides you with. The direction I would go would be to implement a custom Menu that provides the functionality and form you are looking for.

Comment: I know I can implement something custom, but I really want it to look and behave like the one Apple did in Files app. I think it is doable using UIKit.